# Where does the mining reward in regtest go?

Tags: bitcoind, mining-reward, regtest

After using the `bitcoind -regtest generate 1` command, where does the mining reward go? I tried list accounts and check balance for account "", but the balance always showed 0.000000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To you, but with a delay.

What you're observing is the maturity period: the coins generated by a block can only be moved after there are another 100 blocks on top.

If you generate another 100, your balance will start increasing.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the mining reward address with bitcoind?

Comment: Yes, use the `generatetoaddress` RPC (which mines to an address of your choice) rather than the `generate` RPC (which mines to a fresh wallet address).